# How to make array members variable?

Tags: zig

I get this error while trying to build:
`suds.zig:29:26: error: cannot assign to constant`
This is my code:

```
const std = @import("std");

const SIZE: u8 = 9;

fn create_board() [SIZE][SIZE]u8 {
    var board: [SIZE][SIZE]u8 = undefined;
    for (&board) |*row| {
        row.* = [_]u8{0} ** 9;
    }
    return board;
}

pub fn main() !void {

    const halloc = std.heap.page_allocator;
    var board = create_board();

    for (board, 0..) |row, r| {
        for (row, 0..) |field, c| {
            while (true) {
                std.io.getStdOut().writer().print("Enter number for row {}, column {} - '0' if empty: ", .{r, c}) catch @panic("Output error!");
                const field_input = std.io.getStdIn().reader().readUntilDelimiterAlloc(halloc, '\n', 4) catch @panic("Input error!");
                defer halloc.free(field_input);
                const parse_input = std.fmt.parseInt(u8, field_input, 10) catch {
                    std.io.getStdOut().writer().print("\nInvalid integer, try again.\n", .{}) catch @panic("Output error!");
                    continue;
                };
                if (parse_input <= SIZE) {
                    field = parse_input;
                    break;
                } else {
                    std.io.getStdOut().writer().print("\nValue too large, try again.\n", .{}) catch @panic("Output error!");
                    continue;
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So I cannot assign anything to `field` because it was declared as constant apparently. How do I declare it as variable?

Changing it to pointers (`for (&row, 0..) |*field, c| {`) yields the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capture values in `for` loops are implicitly marked as `const`. (I don't see this mentioned in the [docs](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#for), though. Perhaps the rule that [function parameters are immutable](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Pass-by-value-Parameters) also applies to capture values.)

This means that `row` is `const`, which is passed to `field`, which becomes `const *const u8` instead of `const *u8`. You can work around this by declaring the row separately.

```
for (0..board.len) |r| {
    var row = &board[r];
    for (row, 0..) |*field, c| {
        // ...

        field.* = parse_input;
    }
}
```